# Ownership of values whose variables are shadowed

Tags: rust, ownership

See some code below:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyString {
    a: String,
}

impl MyString {
    fn new(s: &str) -> Self {
        MyString { a: String::from(s) }
    }
}

impl Deref for MyString {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.a
    }
}

impl Drop for MyString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{} dropped!", self.a);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test1 = MyString::new("test1");
    let mut test1 = MyString::new(&test1);
    println!("shadow variable test1");
    test1.a = String::from("test2");
}
```

I thought there should be a compile error because test1 is still borrowed.

However, there's no compile error, and the result is

```
shadow variables test1
test2 dropped
test1 dropped
```

So if a variable is shadowed, the value is still valid in the current scope.
But who is its owner?

Comment: "_I thought there should be a compile error because test1 is still borrowed._" → no it isn't, the borrow is released immediately after the call to `MyString::new(&test1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an ownership standpoint, your code is exactly equivalent to:

```
fn main() {
    let mut test1_1 = MyString::new("test1");
    let mut test1_2 = MyString::new(&test1_1);
    println!("shadow variable test1");
    test1_2.a = String::from("test2");
}
```

So `test1_1` is dropped when it goes out of scope at the end of the `main` function.

Note also that `test1_2` does *not* borrow `test1_1`, the borrow only lasts for as long as the call to `MyString::new(&test1)`. Afterwards there is no connection between the two variables.

Comment: Does test1 value still have an owner although the first test1 variable is already invalid? How the compiler know which is its owner?

Comment: The first `test1` variable is not "invalid", it is _shadowed_. Which means that it still exists even if your code can no longer designate it. In fact this kind of variable shadowing happens all the time under the hood in the compiler (see [static single assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)).